# How to resolve file missing on remote server

Tags: php

Please i need your help on this. Any time i transfer this file into remote server through ftp, it often get missing on the server somehow. I always have to re-upload it. Recently all i get are errors like this `PHP Warning:  require(maxUpload.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.
I know the errors are due to due to my `require()` function.
 Is there any reason this file keep getting lost on the remote server?

```
<?php
require 'maxUpload.class.php'
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>Upload Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $myUpload = new maxUpload(); 
    //$myUpload->setUploadLocation(getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    $myUpload->uploadFile();
?>
</body>
```

This is maxUpload.class.php

```
<?php
class maxUpload{
    var $uploadLocation;
    function maxUpload(){
        $this->uploadLocation = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."/images". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
    }
    function setUploadLocation($dir){
        $this->uploadLocation = $dir;
    }

    function showUploadForm($msg='',$error=''){
?>
       <div id="container">

            <div id="content">
<?php
if ($msg != ''){
    echo '<p class="msg">'.$msg.'</p>';
} else if ($error != ''){
    echo '<p class="emsg">'.$error.'</p>';

}
?>
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                     <center>
                         <label>Upload Image (Jpeg Only)
                             <input name="myfile" type="file" size="30" />
                         </label>
                         <label>
                             <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" />
                         </label>
                     </center>
                 </form>
             </div>
         </div>
<?php
    }

    function uploadFile(){
        if (!isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
            $this->showUploadForm();
        } else {
            $msg = '';
            $error = '';
            if (!file_exists($this->uploadLocation)){
                $error = "The target directory doesn't exists!";
            } else if (!is_writeable($this->uploadLocation)) {
                $error = "The target directory is not writeable!";
            } else {
                $target_path = $this->uploadLocation . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']);

                if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
                    $msg = basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']).
                    " <b style='color:white;'>was uploaded successfully!</b>";
                } else{
                    $error = "The upload process failed!";
                }
            }

            $this->showUploadForm($msg,$error);
        }

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not missing, this error also indicate that you are giving wrong path to the file, make sure `maxUpload.class.php` is in same folder. you need to give correct path to `require()` function where to locate this file.

You can also use `getcwd()` to `Gets the current working directory.`

something like `echo getcwd();`. you can use `chdir()` function to go to specific folder by giving correct path `chdir("../");`

i don't know your folder structure but add

`require '../maxUpload.class.php'` or

`require '/maxUpload.class.php'`

Comment: Thanks Archish. both maxUpload.class.php and upload.php inside which is require() are in the same folder like admin. It was working initially until i started experiencing this lately even with require '../maxUpload.class.php'